# accessing rails models from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

How can I access model objects from rails rake task?

If I initialize my rufus scheduler `$scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new` in my rake would that scheduler stay alive since it's from a rake task?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To access a rails model in your rake task you need to load the :environment.

```
task :my_task => [:environment] do
  User.new #...
end
```

You would not call the scheduler within a task but the other way around. You need to start a Rufus scheduler and then call your rake tasks from them.

You need to first

```
# other require statements ...
require 'rake'

# ...

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
scheduler.cron "00 6 * * *" do
  Rake::Task["sometask"].invoke
end
```

Comment: what about the scheduler thread? It gets terminated once the rake task finishes.